# how to highlight's only those cells on which am perforforming drag operation for selection purpose?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here am trying to select multiple cells as per mouse dragging operation,here am able select multiple cells but having small issue,means suppose fisrtly i draggred mouse on 4 cells then these cells got selected means to them one class got assigned  but when am dragging these 4 cells and still mouse is not released and am again substact 2 cells from these 4 dragged cells,means i have dragged mouse on 4 cells and without realesing mouse i dragged back from 2 cells then now there should be 2 cells which are selected
this is the code am referring

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isMouseDown = false;
    var lastTr = -1;

    $('body').mousedown(function () {
        isMouseDown = true;
        $('td').removeClass('highlight');
    })
    .mouseup(function () {
        isMouseDown = false;
    });

    $("table td").hover(function () {
        var ctr = $(this).closest('tr').index();
        lastTr = lastTr === -1 ? ctr : lastTr;

        if (isMouseDown)
            if (lastTr != ctr) {
                $('td').removeClass('highlight');
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass("highlight");              
                var th = $('#example th').eq($(this).index());
                alert(th.text());
            }
        lastTr = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    });


});
```

Comment: Can you please show your html code please ?

Comment: its simple table with <tr></tr> <td></td>